# Convert JSON to Dataframe in Python 3 having an ID

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have to import a file having an ID and JSON field into a DATAFRAME

Could import only the json into a dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    cob_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

json_df = pd.DataFrame(cob_data)
```

However could not add the ID to this dataframe.

The requirement is to select the ID which has a relevant JSON match

Here is a sample example data
[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez07x.png)

```
Format of data 
 ID|JSON
123|JSON_1
234|JSON_2
345|JSON_3
```

Comment: Maybe [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function from padnas module could help